# How to add text fields on an image to generate a meme in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create a meme generator in ASP.NET Core Web API; for that I need to upload an image and allow the user to add text on upper and lower level of the image and save it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the official [System.Drawing.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/) nuget from Microsoft. Microsoft has released `System.Drawing.Common` to provide access to GDI+ graphics functionality cross-platform.

The `Graphics` class has methods also for drawing text:

```
 public void DrawString(string? s, Font font, Brush brush, float x, float y)
```

More information with examples [here](http://%20https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowDoYouUseSystemDrawingInNETCore.aspx)

Comment: Using System.Drawing is [generally not recommended in server applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing?view=netcore-3.1#remarks). You should look at alternatives like [ImageSharp](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp) or [SkiaSharp](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp).